# Force apply filter to sales order grid

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to force apply filer by status to order grid for specific user's role, so he can only sees processed orders. [the same of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEXpQ.jpg),
I get the role name in this code:

```
class OrderDataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context, /* object of "Magento\Backend\App\Action" */
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory  $orderCollection,
        array $addFieldStrategies = [],
        array $addFilterStrategies = [],
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);

        $auth= $context->getAuth();
        $loginUser=$auth->getUser();
        $loginUserRole=$loginUser->getRole();
    }
```

and I want to apply the filter for this role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a custom module if not created.

> **app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> **app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;

/**
 * Order grid extended collection
 */
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session
     */
    protected $_adminSession;

    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession,
        $mainTable = 'sales_order_grid',
        $resourceModel = \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::class
    ) {
        $this->_adminSession = $adminSession;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }
   protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
   {
        $roleData = $this->_adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getData();
        if ($roleData['role_name'] == '[Name of your role here]') {
            $this->getSelect()->where('status = "processing"');
        }
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
   }
}
```